# semantic cluster service like flickr tag clusters

Tags: nlp, semantics, flickr, freebase

Flickr offers tag clusters via its API to help distinguish in what sense you are using a tag. If you put in 'apple' you'll get get back one cluster with Steve Jobs, computers etc and another with fruit, trees etc.

I've noticed that Google Images behaves in a similar manner, offering different collections of images, but I cannot see that Google offers an API to take advantage of this.

Are there any other 'cluster tag' type services out there that help define the meaning of a tag, similar to what Flickr offers? Is there anything like this in Freebase for example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tag clustering API for Freebase or Google Images. Every topic in Freebase and the Google Knowledge Graph has only one possible meaning so there is no need to cluster ambiguous tags together.

However, using the [Freebase Search API](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/ApiSearch), you can look up every topic with the name "Apple" and it will tell you what the most notable type is for each matching topic like this:

filter=(all name{full}:apple)

[Try it out](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?filter=%28all%20name%7Bfull%7D%3aapple%29&indent=true)